# MS EventHub - batch processing events in Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub

I have to read events in batch, from a given queue, up to 1000 messages at once. Reading the documentation, I couldn't find any configuration on EventHub Admin that allows such behavior, neither on Java JDK API (I found only in the .Net API). What could be the best approach to achieve this using Java JDK API?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you confirm that you're speaking of Event Hubs and not Service Bus?  There is no concept of a queue in Event Hubs.   Assuming Event Hubs, please see the samples for the `azure-messaging-eventhubs` package, here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/messaging-eventhubs-readme?view=azure-java-stable

Comment: Hi Jesse,
 Yes. Event Hub. My apologies for using "queue" in my question. Thanks for replying

Comment: Hi Jesse, 
I've been thru this documentation before, but couldn't find any reference or code. Currently I am able to receive message by message, but the behavior I need to achieve is: receive messages in a bulk, containing up to 1000 messages, and not receive individually..

Comment: By "individually" are you talking about partitions?  Which would mean that you're looking for a way to make a single receive call across all partitions for a heterogeneous batch of events?   If so, that is not a pattern that the Event Hubs supports; each partition is an independent entity that requires a dedicated service operation to read.  The closest that you'd get is to make use of the `EventProcessorClient` from the previous examples.

Comment: Hi Jesse, 
By "individually" I meant messages... my Java class that receives messages uses default partition. 

Anyway, I am gonna take a closer look into EventProcessorClient

Many thanks